Understanding most important features from an additional column
I'm fairly new to data science in general and I'm doing some analysis. Let us say I have N rows and D features, and I have a complex neural network model that consumes these, and many more features. I also have 2 additional columns loss_1 and loss_2 that show how much loss the model paid for each row. A higher loss indicates that the row is somewhat important.
I would like to understand the D features with respect to these losses. i.e. I want to understand which of these D features contributes to high losses and try to get a sense of what constitutes "important rows".
The simplest way I went about it is to compute the correlation between the loss and each of the D features, which gave some initial insights, but I would like to make this more structured. I have a few thoughts and questions on how I can proceed

From the correlation, I can identify that a feature di is probably more important than dj, but this does not help me get some insights such as , a combination of these columns is the most important, etc. I cannot combine the features meaningfully here
I can do a PCA on the D features to reduce it to about 30 features (90% variance), and look at the contribution of each feature in the principal components, but this does not take into account the loss columns, which in some ways is the distinguishing factor. I would like some guidance/thoughts on doing a "supervised PCA" and how it works in practice
I tried doing a simple clustering (PCA followed by kmeans) to divide the data into K clusters. From here, I can "aggregate" the loss for each group, and try to compare groups. But I don't know what the right aggregation function is. A simple sum might not be sufficient, since that does not capture the variance of the losses in the group. For instance, the composition of a specific group probably has no insight on the loss at all, and (2) this is not super explainable, since it goes back to the initial question of "Which of these D features are important and contribute highly to the loss"
How I combine loss_1 and loss_2 is also an interesting problem. They may or may not be correlated, and the importance is a combination of loss_1 and loss_2. In essence I need to be comparing a set of D features against a set of L features, instead of D to 1. Not sure if it makes the problem harder.
As a follow up to the previous, is there a way to compute the correlation between 1 column and a set of columns, i.e. what is the correlation of feature di against loss_1 and loss_2 as a single score.

I believe most of these thoughts are in the right direction, but I would like some guidance on piecing it all together and making it meaningful.
TLDR: given D features and an additional column that contains an importance score, how to determine what combination of features determines an "important row". It is important that these features are explainable, and not embeddings.
